# How can I create a function that uses loc over multiple columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, function

I have a number of columns in a pandas dataframe where any values that are less than or equal to zero I want to change to NaN. I'm relatively new to python. I know copying and pasting code over multiple lines is a no-no, but I've struggled with writing functions so far. I would imagine there's an easier way to do this, but I haven't figured it out yet. What can I do?

```
df.loc[df['col1'] <= 0, 'col1'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['col2'] <= 0, 'col2'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['col3'] <= 0, 'col3'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['col4'] <= 0, 'col4'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.where`, which would replace the values that doesn't satisfy a condition with `NaN`:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
df = df.where(df[cols] > 0)
```